# My recyclerview data keeps getting doubled when i switch to some other fragment and return to that fragment which has the recyclerview

Tags: android

I have a MainActivity where I replace the fragments in a FrameLayout using getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction.replace() and the PositionsFragment as given below.

When I open PositionFragment initially, data is perfectly displayed, but when I switch to dashboard and then again switch to PositionsFragment, the cards in the recyclerview get doubled.

They get doubled every time I switch. I tried clearing the arrayList using productList.clear(); but didn't work.

MainActivity where I replace the fragments.

```
case R.id.nav_dashboard:           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new DashboardFragment()).commit();
                toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
                break;
            case R.id.nav_positions:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new PositionsFragment()).commit();
                toolbar.setTitle("Positions");
                break;
```

PositionsFragment

```
public class PositionsFragment extends Fragment{
    public static Spinner spinner;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ArrayList<Products> productList=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> positionsArray;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    public PositionsFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_positions, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View v, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
        fab=v.findViewById(R.id.positionsFab);
        progressBar=v.findViewById(R.id.progressBarPositions);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spinner=v.findViewById(R.id.positionsSpinner);
        recyclerView=v.findViewById(R.id.positionsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        productList.clear();
        new fetchDataPositions(new OnPositionsFetched() {
            @Override
            public void OnPositionsFetched() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                positionsArray=fetchDataPositions.getArrayList();
                for (int i=0;i<positionsArray.size();i++){
                    productList.add(new Products(//data));
                }
                final PositionsRecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter=new PositionsRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),productList,getActivity());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
            }
        }).execute(url);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.positions_spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your adapter?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the list in Adapter constructor as:

```
public PositionsRecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Products> productList,Context 
context) {
//local product list in adapter
if(mProductList!=null){
     mProductList.clear();
     mProductList.addAll(productList);
   }

}
```

Or can create the method in your adapter and call it before adding new data.

```
public void clearProductList(){
   mProductList.clear();
}
```

Comment: Tried both, same result

Comment: @DivijGupta which approach you tried constructor base or method base?

Comment: @DivijGupta clear positionsArray as well before fetching data.

Comment: Solved it! I wasn't clearing a static array in the fetchDataPositions function.

Comment: @DivijGupta glad to hear to that

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it is evident that you have kept the productList as class member, and have done  productList.clear(); only once. Either keep the list local or clear it just before the loop inside your fetchDataPositions() callback.

Answer (score 0):

When fragment is detach his view is destroyed. So in described case your view is created twice and onViewCreated called twice. You need to stop requesting your data if fragment instance is destroyed (this is what happened when you call replace) because now you will have a memory leak. To do network request right you need to have some object which haven't
connected with fragment/activity lifecycle rotation re-creation etc. You may start your network call and listen for result from some other retained instance fragment for example. This code have a lot of problems, so start from learning more about managing fragment, and fragment retained instance. Good solution will be start using google arch components ViewModel. It will help you avoid doing the same mistakes. Good luck!